# MYSql - data from one table is not updating to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables- "customers" and "returns". I need to get customerid into the returns table. I have set the customerid as a FK in the returns table. With the query below, its returning 0 rows(s) affected. How can I get the data in the returns table? Thank You!

```
update returns
inner join customers on returns.customers_customerid = customers.customerid
set returns.customers_customerid = customers.customerid
```

Comment: if that FK has no current values in it, how will line 2 work? (tip it won't)

Comment: ah-got it! Thank you, Sir!